# Outlook - Non sending Mailbox

Tags: outlook, exchange

I want to create a Mailbox, that can be accessed from multiple users, use the exchange adress book, etc. But i don't want mails to be send. Either those mails shall be blocked or automaticly redirected to another adress. Still an item in the SendItems of the Mailbox shall be created.

How to achive this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure *why* you'd want to do this... but here's how you do anyway.

In Exchange 2007 and 2010 you can create a Hub Transport rule to silently drop all messages sent from this account, and these should also appear in the Sent Items as you wish. You can also make the transport rule redirect to another address if you so desire.

For Exchange 2003, you'll be limited to a third party product.

In both cases, you'll need to grant other users either the ability to "Send As" this account or Full Control over the mailbox.